# SVG-маска «растекается» по краям холста

Tags: html, css, svg, google-chrome, css-animation

У меня есть анимированный svg, который анимирует эффект «gleam/shear». Однако маска не работает на краях поля svg. Я не могу понять, почему он виден по краям.

edit - Похоже, это проблема, связанная с хромом, но я еще не нашел решения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
    background: #671717;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 260px;
}

#fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to {
    animation: fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to__to 600ms linear 1 normal forwards
}

@keyframes fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to__to {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-158.186752px, 357.723397px)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(707.836896px, 139.920000px)
    }
}

#fun-stuff-8-goooood-one {
    max-width: 300px
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<svg cache-id="712f8e74e2a84671a5d2ce2936cc88e4" id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="12 102 535 326" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">
<linearGradient id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill" x1="192.700000" y1="33.970000" x2="344.190000" y2="296.360000" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill-0" offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)"/><stop id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill-1" offset="31%" stop-color="rgb(255,255,252)"/>
<stop id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill-2" offset="54%" stop-color="rgb(255,254,242)"/>
<stop id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill-3" offset="75%" stop-color="rgb(255,252,226)"/><stop id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill-4" offset="94%" stop-color="rgb(255,250,203)"/>
<stop id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill-5" offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(255,249,195)"/></linearGradient>
<g id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-clip-group" clip-path="url(#fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-clipping-paths)">
<clipPath id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-clipping-paths">
<path id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam-mask" d="M534.590000,171.480000C530.700000,176.920000,495.170000,225.230000,446.060000,246.020000C445.237815,246.365879,444.367920,246.585039,443.480000,246.670000C437.040000,247.310000,429.420000,248.030000,420.790000,248.830000C406.090000,280.370000,368.240000,290.700000,334.670000,299.830000C310.940000,306.310000,288.520000,312.430000,274.990000,324.460000C271.650027,327.445836,266.599973,327.445836,263.260000,324.460000C249.730000,312.460000,227.310000,306.310000,203.570000,299.830000C170.010000,290.670000,132.160000,280.340000,117.460000,248.830000C108.830000,248.030000,101.220000,247.310000,94.770000,246.670000C93.884232,246.578738,93.017584,246.352802,92.200000,246C43.070000,225.200000,7.550000,176.900000,3.660000,171.460000C1.461420,168.389667,1.461420,164.260333,3.660000,161.190000C7.550000,155.750000,43.080000,107.450000,92.200000,86.660000C93.018235,86.310929,93.884818,86.088383,94.770000,86C100.850000,85.400000,107.990000,84.720000,116.040000,84C129.590000,49.870000,168.800000,39.160000,203.580000,29.670000C227.310000,23.190000,249.730000,17.070000,263.260000,5.040000C266.591312,2.036791,271.648301,2.019561,275,5C288.530000,17,310.950000,23.150000,334.680000,29.630000C369.460000,39.120000,408.680000,49.820000,422.220000,83.960000C430.270000,84.700000,437.410000,85.380000,443.490000,85.960000C444.378421,86.048303,445.248312,86.270834,446.070000,86.620000C495.200000,107.420000,530.720000,155.710000,534.600000,161.150000C536.824366,164.235294,536.820336,168.399018,534.590000,171.480000Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.24000000000000 100.52000000000000)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
</clipPath>
<path id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-border-b" d="M534.590000,171.480000C530.700000,176.920000,495.170000,225.230000,446.060000,246.020000C445.237815,246.365879,444.367920,246.585039,443.480000,246.670000C437.040000,247.310000,429.420000,248.030000,420.790000,248.830000C406.090000,280.370000,368.240000,290.700000,334.670000,299.830000C310.940000,306.310000,288.520000,312.430000,274.990000,324.460000C271.650027,327.445836,266.599973,327.445836,263.260000,324.460000C249.730000,312.460000,227.310000,306.310000,203.570000,299.830000C170.010000,290.670000,132.160000,280.340000,117.460000,248.830000C108.830000,248.030000,101.220000,247.310000,94.770000,246.670000C93.884232,246.578738,93.017584,246.352802,92.200000,246C43.070000,225.200000,7.550000,176.900000,3.660000,171.460000C1.461420,168.389667,1.461420,164.260333,3.660000,161.190000C7.550000,155.750000,43.080000,107.450000,92.200000,86.660000C93.018235,86.310929,93.884818,86.088383,94.770000,86C100.850000,85.400000,107.990000,84.720000,116.040000,84C129.590000,49.870000,168.800000,39.160000,203.580000,29.670000C227.310000,23.190000,249.730000,17.070000,263.260000,5.040000C266.591312,2.036791,271.648301,2.019561,275,5C288.530000,17,310.950000,23.150000,334.680000,29.630000C369.460000,39.120000,408.680000,49.820000,422.220000,83.960000C430.270000,84.700000,437.410000,85.380000,443.490000,85.960000C444.378421,86.048303,445.248312,86.270834,446.070000,86.620000C495.200000,107.420000,530.720000,155.710000,534.600000,161.150000C536.824366,164.235294,536.820336,168.399018,534.590000,171.480000Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.24000000000000 100.52000000000000)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg" d="M269.120000,317.900000C254.050000,304.490000,230.640000,298.100000,205.900000,291.350000C171.230000,281.880000,135.380000,272.100000,123.900000,241.280000L123.620000,240.520000L122.510000,240.420000C112.160000,239.470000,103.130000,238.620000,95.680000,237.890000C48.830000,218.060000,14.680000,171.730000,10.880000,166.350000C14.730000,160.970000,48.880000,114.630000,95.680000,94.810000C102.850000,94.100000,111.510000,93.280000,121.410000,92.380000L122.570000,92.270000L122.810000,91.470000C133,58.090000,170.050000,48,205.900000,38.190000C230.640000,31.430000,254.050000,25.040000,269.120000,11.630000C284.190000,25.040000,307.610000,31.430000,332.350000,38.190000C368.200000,47.970000,405.280000,58.090000,415.480000,91.470000L415.720000,92.270000L416.880000,92.380000C426.780000,93.280000,435.440000,94.100000,442.610000,94.810000C489.460000,114.640000,523.610000,160.970000,527.410000,166.350000C523.560000,171.730000,489.410000,218.060000,442.610000,237.890000C435.160000,238.620000,426.130000,239.470000,415.780000,240.420000L414.670000,240.520000L414.390000,241.280000C402.870000,272.100000,367.020000,281.880000,332.390000,291.350000C307.610000,298.100000,284.190000,304.490000,269.120000,317.900000Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.24000000000000 100.52000000000000)" fill="url(#fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-bg-fill)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-border-a" d="M269.130000,305.790000L267.200000,304.630000C251.030000,294.810000,230.260000,289.130000,210.200000,283.630000C175.360000,274.120000,145.260000,265.900000,135.270000,239.160000L133,233.060000L124.050000,232.230000C115.120000,231.420000,107.180000,230.670000,100.390000,230.010000L99.700000,230L99.160000,229.750000C69.450000,216.350000,41.280000,188.750000,24.830000,167.380000L24.070000,166.380000L24.830000,165.380000C41.290000,144,69.460000,116.400000,99.160000,103L99.710000,102.760000L100.350000,102.700000C106.840000,102.060000,114.410000,101.350000,122.880000,100.580000L132.270000,99.710000L134.270000,93.220000C143.140000,64.220000,174.200000,55.710000,210.160000,45.890000C230.260000,40.410000,251.040000,34.730000,267.160000,24.890000L269.090000,23.720000L271.010000,24.890000C287.180000,34.720000,307.960000,40.390000,328.010000,45.890000C364.010000,55.710000,395.010000,64.190000,403.910000,93.210000L405.910000,99.710000L415.300000,100.570000C423.780000,101.350000,431.350000,102.060000,437.850000,102.700000L438.490000,102.760000L439.030000,103C468.750000,116.420000,496.910000,144,513.360000,165.380000L514.120000,166.380000L513.360000,167.380000C496.900000,188.740000,468.740000,216.380000,439.030000,229.750000L438.490000,230L437.850000,230.060000C431.060000,230.720000,423.130000,231.470000,414.200000,232.280000L405.260000,233.110000L402.960000,239.230000C392.960000,265.970000,362.870000,274.230000,328.030000,283.700000C307.940000,289.180000,287.150000,294.860000,271.030000,304.700000ZM101.800000,226C108.430000,226.650000,116.120000,227.370000,124.800000,228.160000L137.670000,229.340000L140.950000,238.160000C150.180000,262.860000,178.950000,270.720000,212.330000,279.820000C232.120000,285.220000,252.560000,290.820000,269.170000,300.390000C285.770000,290.800000,306.170000,285.220000,326.010000,279.820000C359.350000,270.720000,388.140000,262.820000,397.380000,238.150000L400.680000,229.340000L413.540000,228.160000C422.170000,227.370000,429.870000,226.650000,436.490000,226C464.620000,213.130000,491.430000,187,507.490000,166.370000C491.400000,145.740000,464.590000,119.610000,436.490000,106.730000C430.160000,106.120000,422.830000,105.430000,414.630000,104.730000L401.130000,103.490000L398.280000,94.140000C390,67.220000,360.350000,59.120000,326,49.730000C306.210000,44.330000,285.770000,38.730000,269.160000,29.160000C252.550000,38.750000,232.100000,44.330000,212.310000,49.730000C177.900000,59.120000,148.210000,67.220000,140,94.070000L137.130000,103.420000L123.640000,104.660000C115.450000,105.410000,108.120000,106.100000,101.790000,106.660000C73.660000,119.530000,46.850000,145.660000,30.790000,166.300000C46.860000,187,73.670000,213.110000,101.800000,226Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.24000000000000 100.52000000000000)" fill="rgb(202,148,43)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
<path id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-txt" d="M237.720000,118.720000C237.720000,124.563173,232.983173,129.300000,227.140000,129.300000C221.296827,129.300000,216.560000,124.563173,216.560000,118.720000C216.560000,112.876827,221.296827,108.140000,227.140000,108.140000C229.945990,108.140000,232.637055,109.254675,234.621190,111.238810C236.605325,113.222945,237.720000,115.914010,237.720000,118.720000ZM259,108.140000C254.720789,108.140000,250.862938,110.717734,249.225355,114.671209C247.587772,118.624684,248.492951,123.175331,251.518810,126.201190C254.544669,129.227049,259.095316,130.132228,263.048791,128.494645C267.002266,126.857062,269.580000,122.999211,269.580000,118.720000C269.580000,112.876827,264.843173,108.140000,259,108.140000ZM188.510000,135.560000C192.650000,142.900000,194.740000,151.560000,194.740000,161.190000C194.798819,167.734828,193.621537,174.231931,191.270000,180.340000C189.120266,185.964181,185.761074,191.047349,181.430000,195.230000C177.510356,199.033356,172.767957,201.883586,167.570000,203.560000C162.760000,205.050000,154.980000,205.780000,143.790000,205.780000L120.290000,205.780000L120.290000,114.310000L143.530000,114.310000C156.320000,114.310000,165.710000,115.920000,172.240000,119.310000L172.240000,119.310000C178.860000,122.630000,184.340000,128.120000,188.530000,135.560000ZM163.610000,144C160.170000,140.610000,154.180000,138.890000,145.830000,138.890000L145.290000,138.890000L145.290000,181.090000L147.780000,181.090000C155.670000,181.090000,159.400000,180.040000,161.140000,179.160000C163.685768,177.737919,165.723950,175.556401,166.970000,172.920000C168.770922,169.158708,169.635497,165.017669,169.490000,160.850000C169.490000,153.380000,167.560000,147.860000,163.610000,144ZM247.610000,135.680000L272.330000,135.680000L272.330000,205.810000L247.630000,205.810000L247.630000,204C246.850000,204.410000,246.060000,204.790000,245.280000,205.120000C241.618833,206.619763,237.696345,207.377749,233.740000,207.350000C224.580000,207.350000,216.580000,203.780000,209.960000,196.740000C203.340000,189.700000,200.100000,181.070000,200.100000,170.830000C200.100000,160.290000,203.310000,151.450000,209.650000,144.590000C215.636675,137.831629,224.261894,134.004279,233.290000,134.100000C237.455320,134.076309,241.580930,134.910281,245.410000,136.550000C246.160000,136.870000,246.900000,137.230000,247.630000,137.610000ZM228.130000,161.150000C225.850000,163.580000,224.740000,166.700000,224.740000,170.690000C224.572634,174.245343,225.820291,177.722243,228.210000,180.360000C230.352567,182.675453,233.360151,183.997628,236.514789,184.010899C239.669426,184.024169,242.688028,182.727345,244.850000,180.430000C247.160000,178,248.270000,174.790000,248.270000,170.630000C248.270000,166.470000,247.160000,163.480000,244.880000,161.110000C242.666533,158.798035,239.568305,157.545637,236.370000,157.670000C233.254847,157.549020,230.245686,158.811989,228.150000,161.120000ZM323.660000,135.680000L348.400000,135.680000L348.400000,205.810000L323.680000,205.810000L323.680000,204C322.900000,204.410000,322.110000,204.790000,321.330000,205.120000C317.668833,206.619763,313.746345,207.377749,309.790000,207.350000C300.630000,207.350000,292.630000,203.780000,286.010000,196.740000C279.390000,189.700000,276.150000,181.070000,276.150000,170.830000C276.150000,160.290000,279.360000,151.450000,285.710000,144.590000C291.692780,137.832095,300.314823,134.004535,309.340000,134.100000C313.505403,134.075451,317.631187,134.909458,321.460000,136.550000C322.210000,136.870000,322.950000,137.230000,323.680000,137.610000ZM304.200000,161.120000C301.920000,163.550000,300.810000,166.670000,300.810000,170.660000C300.642634,174.215343,301.890291,177.692243,304.280000,180.330000C306.422567,182.645453,309.430151,183.967628,312.584789,183.980899C315.739426,183.994169,318.758028,182.697345,320.920000,180.400000C323.230000,177.970000,324.350000,174.760000,324.350000,170.600000C324.350000,166.440000,323.240000,163.450000,320.950000,161.080000C318.736533,158.768035,315.638305,157.515637,312.440000,157.640000C309.313167,157.520614,306.294671,158.795416,304.200000,161.120000ZM420.310000,135.650000L361,135.650000L361,158L380.730000,158L353.370000,205.750000L415.370000,205.750000L415.370000,183.400000L393.070000,183.400000ZM175.490000,226.330000L175.490000,230.720000L184.620000,230.720000L184.620000,226.330000ZM195.220000,215.060000L195.220000,236L204.370000,236C212,236,216,232.080000,216,225.470000C216,219.470000,212,215.060000,204.120000,215.060000ZM200.500000,232.170000L200.500000,218.810000L203.670000,218.810000C208.120000,218.810000,210.550000,221.260000,210.550000,225.560000C210.550000,229.860000,208.330000,232.170000,203.850000,232.170000ZM225.670000,215.060000L225.670000,236L240.250000,236L240.250000,232.250000L231,232.250000L231,227.150000L239.660000,227.150000L239.660000,223.410000L231,223.410000L231,218.800000L240,218.800000L240,215.050000ZM250.250000,215.060000L250.250000,236L265,236L265,231.670000L255.510000,231.670000L255.510000,215.060000ZM268.410000,215.060000L268.410000,219.420000L275.870000,219.420000L275.870000,236L281.150000,236L281.150000,219.420000L288.680000,219.420000L288.680000,215.060000ZM302.050000,215.060000L292.920000,236.060000L298.330000,236.060000L300.330000,231.240000L309.330000,231.240000L311.330000,236.060000L316.740000,236.060000L307.520000,215.060000ZM304.810000,220.220000L307.940000,227.840000L301.710000,227.840000ZM346.720000,214.810000C341.720000,214.810000,339.660000,218.100000,339.660000,220.740000C339.617844,222.605251,340.605538,224.342361,342.230000,225.260000C340.276400,226.211851,339.029384,228.186938,339.010000,230.360000C339.010000,232.940000,340.920000,236.310000,346.690000,236.310000C352.460000,236.310000,354.370000,232.840000,354.370000,230.390000C354.346073,228.207956,353.097356,226.224699,351.140000,225.260000C352.811191,224.366228,353.833423,222.604427,353.780000,220.710000C353.780000,218,351.700000,214.780000,346.720000,214.780000ZM343.650000,229.950000C343.742586,228.327707,345.109954,227.074026,346.734171,227.122256C348.358388,227.170487,349.648957,228.503094,349.645118,230.128023C349.641279,231.752951,348.344427,233.079445,346.720000,233.120000C345.876368,233.141587,345.062658,232.806848,344.478422,232.197873C343.894187,231.588898,343.593463,230.762013,343.650000,229.920000ZM344.200000,221.020000C344.136502,220.294351,344.373366,219.574409,344.855306,219.028211C345.337245,218.482012,346.022091,218.157350,346.750000,218.130000C348.350000,218.130000,349.210000,219.540000,349.210000,221.050000C349.265062,221.763889,349.033242,222.470272,348.565880,223.012713C348.098517,223.555153,347.434182,223.888885,346.720000,223.940000C345.212785,223.822990,344.085118,222.507378,344.200000,221ZM363.710000,226.360000L363.710000,230.750000L372.840000,230.750000L372.840000,226.360000Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.24000000000000 100.52000000000000)" fill="rgb(35,31,32)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
    <g id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to" transform="translate(-158.186752,357.723397)"><image id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam" width="530" height="557" xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/NfMvQ6Kp/streak.png" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" transform="translate(-265,-278.500000)"/></g></g></svg>
</div>
</body>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG Mask is “bleeding” on canvas edges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67736210/7394871) от участника  [@VeggieBot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9799325/veggiebot).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67736210/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что у Chrome возникли проблемы с применением обтравочного контура (clipping path) к изображениям.
И это становится немного хуже, когда изображение движется - как в вашем случае.

Однако есть простое решение. Вместо этого `clip-path` используйте `<mask>`.

И я ожидаю, что переключение блеска с изображения на объект SVG с помощью `linearGradient` также будет работать нормально.

Пример использования маски вместо clip path

(Обратите внимание, что я обрезал SVG, чтобы просто показать важные части)

```css
.container {
    background: #671717;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 260px;
}

#fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to {
    animation: fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to__to 3600ms linear 1 normal forwards
}

@keyframes fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to__to {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-158.186752px, 357px)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(707.836896px, 139px)
    }
}

#fun-stuff-8-goooood-one {
    max-width: 300px
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<svg cache-id="712f8e74e2a84671a5d2ce2936cc88e4" id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="12 102 535 326" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">
  <g id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-clip-group" mask="url(#fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-clipping-paths)">
    <mask id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-clipping-paths">
      <path id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam-mask" d="M534.590000,171.480000C530.700000,176.920000,495.170000,225.230000,446.060000,246.020000C445.237815,246.365879,444.367920,246.585039,443.480000,246.670000C437.040000,247.310000,429.420000,248.030000,420.790000,248.830000C406.090000,280.370000,368.240000,290.700000,334.670000,299.830000C310.940000,306.310000,288.520000,312.430000,274.990000,324.460000C271.650027,327.445836,266.599973,327.445836,263.260000,324.460000C249.730000,312.460000,227.310000,306.310000,203.570000,299.830000C170.010000,290.670000,132.160000,280.340000,117.460000,248.830000C108.830000,248.030000,101.220000,247.310000,94.770000,246.670000C93.884232,246.578738,93.017584,246.352802,92.200000,246C43.070000,225.200000,7.550000,176.900000,3.660000,171.460000C1.461420,168.389667,1.461420,164.260333,3.660000,161.190000C7.550000,155.750000,43.080000,107.450000,92.200000,86.660000C93.018235,86.310929,93.884818,86.088383,94.770000,86C100.850000,85.400000,107.990000,84.720000,116.040000,84C129.590000,49.870000,168.800000,39.160000,203.580000,29.670000C227.310000,23.190000,249.730000,17.070000,263.260000,5.040000C266.591312,2.036791,271.648301,2.019561,275,5C288.530000,17,310.950000,23.150000,334.680000,29.630000C369.460000,39.120000,408.680000,49.820000,422.220000,83.960000C430.270000,84.700000,437.410000,85.380000,443.490000,85.960000C444.378421,86.048303,445.248312,86.270834,446.070000,86.620000C495.200000,107.420000,530.720000,155.710000,534.600000,161.150000C536.824366,164.235294,536.820336,168.399018,534.590000,171.480000Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.24000000000000 100.52000000000000)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
    </mask>
    <path id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-border-b" d="M534.590000,171.480000C530.700000,176.920000,495.170000,225.230000,446.060000,246.020000C445.237815,246.365879,444.367920,246.585039,443.480000,246.670000C437.040000,247.310000,429.420000,248.030000,420.790000,248.830000C406.090000,280.370000,368.240000,290.700000,334.670000,299.830000C310.940000,306.310000,288.520000,312.430000,274.990000,324.460000C271.650027,327.445836,266.599973,327.445836,263.260000,324.460000C249.730000,312.460000,227.310000,306.310000,203.570000,299.830000C170.010000,290.670000,132.160000,280.340000,117.460000,248.830000C108.830000,248.030000,101.220000,247.310000,94.770000,246.670000C93.884232,246.578738,93.017584,246.352802,92.200000,246C43.070000,225.200000,7.550000,176.900000,3.660000,171.460000C1.461420,168.389667,1.461420,164.260333,3.660000,161.190000C7.550000,155.750000,43.080000,107.450000,92.200000,86.660000C93.018235,86.310929,93.884818,86.088383,94.770000,86C100.850000,85.400000,107.990000,84.720000,116.040000,84C129.590000,49.870000,168.800000,39.160000,203.580000,29.670000C227.310000,23.190000,249.730000,17.070000,263.260000,5.040000C266.591312,2.036791,271.648301,2.019561,275,5C288.530000,17,310.950000,23.150000,334.680000,29.630000C369.460000,39.120000,408.680000,49.820000,422.220000,83.960000C430.270000,84.700000,437.410000,85.380000,443.490000,85.960000C444.378421,86.048303,445.248312,86.270834,446.070000,86.620000C495.200000,107.420000,530.720000,155.710000,534.600000,161.150000C536.824366,164.235294,536.820336,168.399018,534.590000,171.480000Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.24000000000000 100.52000000000000)" fill="rgb(128,128,255)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
 
    <g id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam_to" transform="translate(0,357.723397)"><image id="fun-stuff-8-goooood-one-gleam" width="530" height="557" xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/NfMvQ6Kp/streak.png" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" transform="translate(-265,-278.500000)"/></g></g></svg>
</div>
</body>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67737683/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: Это не `gleam/shear`, а `В-с-с-с - В-с-с-с`.